# Django FileResponse: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, django, windows

I have been trying to return a file using Django FileResponse, but faced a problem: file instance cannot be deleted after response has been sent. Before this implementation, I have used tempfile module, but it also did not work.

```
from rest_framework import views, status
from django.http import FileResponse
import os


class DownloadShoppingCartView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            with open('test.txt', 'w+') as file:
                file.write('supertest\n')

            return FileResponse(
                open(file.name, mode='rb'),
                as_attachment=True,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print('There will be exception handling')
        finally:
            """I also have been trying to put here time.sleep(5),
 but there was no positive result.
            """
            os.remove(file.name)
```

Full traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/recipes/download_shopping_cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Justm\dev\foodgram-project-react\backend\recipes\views.py", line 141, in get
    os.remove(file.name)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'test.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` clause runs before `return`.

Since you `open(file.name, mode='rb')`, which will only be closed after `return` and the response has been sent, `os.remove` in the `finally` clause cannot access the file.

You can implement a remove-after-close file proxy.

```py
import os

from django.core.files.utils import FileProxyMixin


class RemoveAfterCloseFileProxy(FileProxyMixin):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.name = file.name

    def close(self):
        if not self.closed:
            self.file.close()
            try:
                os.remove(self.name)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()
```

Usage:

```py
class DownloadShoppingCartView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            with open('test.txt', 'w+') as file:
                file.write('supertest\n')

            return FileResponse(
                # open(file.name, mode='rb'),                           # Change this
                RemoveAfterCloseFileProxy(open(file.name, mode='rb')),  # to this
                as_attachment=True,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print('There will be exception handling')
        finally:
            # os.remove(file.name)    # Wrap this
            try:                      # in try-except
                os.remove(file.name)  #
            except PermissionError:   #
                pass                  #
```